# 'Pending Add" showing with green plus icon after adding an existing project to my c# solution in visulat studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am developing a C# project..So I have a exising project which I want to add to my project solution...When I am adding the existing project by clicking the add existing project option in my solution..It adds and also run properly..But the problem is that a plus icon with 'Pending add' message showing whenever I hovering the cursor on the plus icon...the new added project is also not showing in the file explorer of my project folder..It is only showing inside the solution explorer of
visual studio...While my other project folders are showing 'checked in' message...

so, How can I solve this problem and 'checked in' my newly added project?
Thanks in advance

Help me solve the problem
[image: how its look]

Comment: Hi, if my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you must first use sourcetree (that is, git version control) to submit the newly added files before "checked in" can be displayed. This is a prompt that only appears when using git for version control.

When modifying a file, "Pending Edits" will be prompted, and a small red check mark (√) will replace the small blue lock in the check-in status on the file displayed in the solution explorer. Use Sourcetree (that is, git version control) can solve the problem by submitting the modified part of the file.

For details, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms181409%28v%3dvs.80%29#pending-additions